# Как сохранить результат работы функции в переменную

Tags: javascript

Сижу не один час за изучением js туплю на ровных вопросах, уж простите(((Есть функция, она после проверок отрисовывает попап, и мне нужно в этой же функции после отрисовки попапа, сохранить отрисованный попап в переменную, и на эту переменную повесить обработчик закрытия попапа.Вот функция

```
`var onMapPinsBlockMousedown = function (e) {
  if (e.button !== 0) {
    return;
  }
  removeCardElement();
  var targetPin;
  if (e.target.classList.contains('map__pin') && !e.target.classList.contains('map__pin--main')) {
    targetPin = e.target;
    // ;
  } else if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG' && e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('map__pin') && !e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('map__pin--main')){
    targetPin = e.target.parentElement;
  }
  if (targetPin) {
    var index = pinsElements.indexOf(targetPin);
    if (index !== -1 && index < adds.length) {
      renderCard(renderOfferCard(adds[index]));
    }
  }
};`
```

Comment: 1. `return то_что_хотите_вернуть` будет результатом работы функции 

2. задать глобальную переменную и перезаписать её внутри функции и потом использовать

Comment: то есть, у Вас есть функция, которая запускает отрисовку `popup` и Вам нужно, чтобы внутри этой же функции вешался обработчик, который бы закрывал этот `popup`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри функции нашла с помощью querySelector этот попап,( return в данной фукции не срабатывает)и повесила на него обработчик, и обработчик на документ, для закрытия по клавиши esc

```
var onMapPinsBlockMousedown = function (e) {
  if (e.button !== 0) {
    return;
  }
  removeCardElement();
  var targetPin;
  if (e.target.classList.contains('map__pin') && !e.target.classList.contains('map__pin--main')) {
    targetPin = e.target;
    // ;
  } else if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG' && e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('map__pin') && !e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('map__pin--main')){
    targetPin = e.target.parentElement;
  }
  if (targetPin) {
    var index = pinsElements.indexOf(targetPin);
    if (index !== -1 && index < adds.length) {
      renderCard(renderOfferCard(adds[index]));
    }
  }
  var cardOnMap = document.querySelector('.map__card');
  document.addEventListener('keydown', onPinEscPress);
  cardOnMap.addEventListener('mousedown', onPinCloseCard);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Как пример вариант.
Сегодня просто делал пример с выводом значений ))

```js
$('[name="button"]').on('click', function() {
    $('#rezult').html(example);
});
var example = function functionName(e) {
    return '<label>Благодарим за отправку '+$('[name="fname"]').val()+' '+$('[name="lname"]').val()+' мы с вами свяжемся!</label>';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="Иван">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="Иванов">
</div>
<button type="button" name="button">Отправить</button>

<div id="rezult"></div>
```